# Como hacer reactiva una query de graphql?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

Tengo un front con vue-apollo que consume un back con consultas graphql. Es un crud de usuarios-ambientes-plantas. Me suceden dos cosas en principio:

- Los usuarios (una vez logueados) solo pueden ver sus ambientes (esto debe ser así). Pero si yo cierro sesión, y vuelvo a iniciar con un nuevo usuario, veo los ambientes del usuario que estaba conectado en la sesión anterior. (cerrar sesión limpia `vuex` y `localStorage`, por lo que no sé si es un problema de cache o si me falta configurar algo para que sea "reactivo" el cambio)
- Cuando se renderiza la lista de ambientes, estos tienen un botón para eliminarlos. Funciona correctamente, pero el elemento eliminado no desaparece si no recargo la página.
- Cuando creo un ambiente nuevo, este se carga correctamente pero no se visualiza en la lista hasta no refrescar el sitio.

Cual sería la manera correcta de conectar la reactividad de vue con el resultado de las queries?

Pongo un pequeño ejemplo de como armo la consulta y como las levanto en el `template`.

En mi componente Ambientes.vue tengo la query

```
<script>
 data(){...},
 methods:{...},
 apollo: {
    getMisAmbientes: gql`
      query {
        getMisAmbientes {
          _id
          nombre
          tipo
          tiempo
        }
      }
    `
  },
 ...
</script>
```

Que se renderiza en el template

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in getMisAmbientes" :key="index">
  <card-ambiente :item="item" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente llegué a una solución así que comparto por si alguien llega esta pregunta alguna vez.

Solo hay que llamar a la query nuevamente, de esta manera

`this.$apollo.queries.<nombreDeLaQuery>.refetch()`. Esto hará que la query se ejecute nuevamente.

-> La query debe estar definida en el mismo componente, en el objeto `Apollo` o debe ser importada. En mi caso, tengo un componente A donde debo refetchear la query, y debo hacerlo desde un componente B. Entonces vuelvo a definir la query en mi componente B (pero nunca la renderizo en mi template) para poder aplicar `this.$apollo.queries.<nombreDeLaQuery>.refetch()`. Esto la actualiza donde la esté renderizando (En este caso, en el componente A).